# Call javascript from WP phonegap

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, cordova

I am trying to write a quick windows phone plugin for phonegap to handle my push notifications.  Ideally I would like all of the notifications / deviceid etc to be passed back to a javascript function so that I can handle them in the same way as my push notifications for android and ios.  however I cannot seem to access the webView.sendJavascript function as I can in android.

In Android I can import the org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView class and do this.webView.  I am unsure how to do the same thing in windows phone using the Cordova.Extensions.Commands namespace as none of the WPCordovaClassLib classes seem to have a webview object.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows Phone 8 WebBrowser control you had a method called [InvokeScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402838%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) who allows you to call a JavaScript function defined in the loaded document, passing an array of strings as parameters for that function. This way you can pass your Notification data to your JavaScript.

Hope This helps.

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed.  took a bit to get it working as I had to access the cordovaView, but does the job.